# prevent sed from writing when encountering error

Tags: sed, error-handling

Is it possible to prevent sed from writing when it encounters an error. Such that

```
sed -e 's/a/b/g' nonExistantFile > fileIDontWantToExist
```

would not create `fileIDontWantToExist` for example. Currently  it outputs a warning sed: can't read `nonExistantFile`: No such file or directory. But it still creates the file `fileIDontWantToExist`.

Answer (score 2):

The output redirection is expanded by the shell, not by sed. You need an `if` statement, like this:

```
if sed '...' input.file > output.file.tmp ; then
    mv output.file.tmp output.file
else
    rm output.file.tmp
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, is this missing ; fi to close the if statement? (Otherwise not working for me).

Answer (score 2):

A one liner:

`test -f nonExistantFile && sed -e 's/a/b/g' nonExistantFile > fileIDontWantToExist`

The invocation of `test` will fail, so sed won't be called.